# Invalid JSON RPC response when creating contract

Tags: solidity, remix, json-rpc, error

I am getting this error while trying to deploy contract on Mainnet via remix.ethereum.org

```
creation of XXXTokenCrowdsale errored:
Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":22,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}
```

The same copy and pasted contract deploys without a problem on Ropsten or Rinkeby testnets using the same interface on remix.ethereum.org injected Web3.

Comment: I found a temporary workaround:
1. using remix, deploy your contract on testnet, e.g rinkeby
2. copy the bytecode from rinkeby etherscan
3. deploy using myetherwallet on mainnet by pasting the bytecode from step 2 .
gas needs to be 3M (3000000) for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (different context but same error code).

As suggested at the bottom of [this github issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3140), use `truffle migrate --reset` instead of just `truffle migrate`, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now, please let us know if it isn't.